# Highstocks - set extremes at export

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock graph with dual pane (top & bottom). I understand that the range selector will read from the xAxis extremes to set the from and to date.

Everytime I add a series, be it to the top or bottom, I will have to invoke : chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(); in order for the range selector to "refresh" the From and To date (if necessary).

Now, the problem comes when I have to do the same steps for my export module.  How do I formulate the extremes into my options array before I pass it to my local export server? Currently, it seems that when I perform the export, the From / To Date is occasionally different from what I have set using xAxis.min and xAxis.max.

Any help/advice is appreciated. Thank you.

---

UPDATE/EDIT:

I am currently using the following options to generate my chart. The chart's xAxis displayed according to the xAxis' min and max values 1315756800000 (12th sep 2011) and 1338134400000 (28th may 2012). However, if I were to copy the following codes and do export on http://export.highcharts.com/, the date becomes 11th sep 2011 to 27th may 2012. Any idea why?

```
{
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "y": 101.3,
          "x": 1315756800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4228571428,
          "x": 1316361600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4657142857,
          "x": 1316966400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.47,
          "x": 1317571200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4714285714,
          "x": 1318176000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4628571428,
          "x": 1318780800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4657142857,
          "x": 1319385600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4542857142,
          "x": 1319990400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4628571428,
          "x": 1320595200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4557142857,
          "x": 1321200000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4614285714,
          "x": 1321804800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.45,
          "x": 1322409600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4414285714,
          "x ": 1323014400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.44,
          "x": 1323619200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4514285714,
          "x": 1324224000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4328571428,
          "x": 1324828800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4214285714,
          "x": 1325433600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4614285714,
          "x": 1326038400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4257142857,
          "x": 1326643200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4742857142,
          "x": 1327248000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4785714285,
          "x": 1327852800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4357142857,
          "x": 1328457600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.3085714285,
          "x": 1329062400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.3071428571,
          "x": 1329667200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.1742857142,
          "x": 1330272000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.1285714285,
          "x": 1330876800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.3242857142,
          "x": 1331481600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4042857142,
          "x": 1332086400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4742857142,
          "x": 1332691200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4771428571,
          "x": 1333296000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.48,
          "x": 1333900800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4771428571,
          "x": 1334505600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4642857142,
          "x": 1335110400000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4628571428,
          "x": 1335715200000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4871428571,
          "x": 1336320000000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4757142857,
          "x": 1336924800000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.4785714285,
          "x": 1337529600000
        },
        {
          "y": 101.475,
          "x": 1338134400000
        }
      ],
      "color": "#5b0f00",
      "type": "line",
      "name": "series 1 (mRL)",
      "yAxis": "testAxis",
      "id": "testSeries1",
      "turboThreshold": 3000
    },
    {
      "name": "series 1 (mRL) Min Max Range",
      "type": "errorbar",
      "id": "primaryWATERLEVELmRLSeries_ErrorBar",
      "linkedTo": "testSeries1",
      "data": [
        [
          1315756800000,
          101.3,
          101.3
        ],
        [
          1316361600000,
          101.36,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1316966400000,
          101.44,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1317571200000,
          101.45,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1318176000000,
          101.46,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1318780800000,
          101.45,
          101.48
        ],
        [
          1319385600000,
          101.45,
          101.48
        ],
        [
          1319990400000,
          101.44,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1320595200000,
          101.44,
          101.48
        ],
        [
          1321200000000,
          101.44,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1321804800000,
          101.44,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1322409600000,
          101.42,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1323014400000,
          101.43,
          101.45
        ],
        [
          1323619200000,
          101.42,
          101.46
        ],
        [
          1324224000000,
          101.44,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1324828800000,
          101.42,
          101.44
        ],
        [
          1325433600000,
          101.41,
          101.43
        ],
        [
          1326038400000,
          101.45,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1326643200000,
          101.4,
          101.46
        ],
        [
          1327248000000,
          101.45,
          101.49
        ],
        [
          1327852800000,
          101.46,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1328457600000,
          101.38,
          101.47
        ],
        [
          1329062400000,
          101.27,
          101.37
        ],
        [
          1329667200000,
          101.28,
          101.33
        ],
        [
          1330272000000,
          101.14,
          101.24
        ],
        [
          1330876800000,
          101.09,
          101.18
        ],
        [
          1331481600000,
          101.21,
          101.43
        ],
        [
          1332086400000,
          101.37,
          101.46
        ],
        [
          1332691200000,
          101.42,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1333296000000,
          101.47,
          101.49
        ],
        [
          1333900800000,
          101.47,
          101.49
        ],
        [
          1334505600000,
          101.46,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1335110400000,
          101.42,
          101.49
        ],
        [
          1335715200000,
          101.43,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1336320000000,
          101.48,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1336924800000,
          101.46,
          101.49
        ],
        [
          1337529600000,
          101.47,
          101.5
        ],
        [
          1338134400000,
          101.46,
          101.5
        ]
      ],
      "zIndex": "1000",
      "yAxis": "testAxis"
    },
    {
      "color": "",
      "type": "line",
      "name": "series 2",
      "yAxis": "testAxis",
      "id": "testSeries",
      "turboThreshold": 3000
    }
  ],
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "id": "testAxis",
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "font": "8px Helvetica",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "enabled": true,
        "text": "axis label",
        "style": {
          "font": "8px Helvetica",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      },
      "top": "0%",
      "height": "100%",
      "opposite": true,
      "onGraph": "primary"
    }
  ],
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "itemStyle": {
      "font": "11px Helvetica",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "min": 1315756800000,
    "max": 1338134400000
  },
  "navigator": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting, it should work as you described (if I understand you correctly). Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle (with some static data in necessary)? We will check this.

Comment: I am pretty certain it will work if I am grabbing the svg and exporting it directly. However, our implementation involves invoking phantomjs from commandline using the java processbuilder, while passing in the options. I would not be able to do a full demonstration of the problem even if I were to create a JSFiddle because the default behaviour of the Export button (if I am not wrong), actually involves grabbing the SVG of the chart that is currently being displayed. For our implementation, we have constructed a servlet that does the export

Comment: So what kind of help you expect from us? You said you have written some code which doesn't work the way you want. How about sharing this code? For me it sounds like your options isn't updated before exporting chart and that's all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any jsFiddle..